# How make post request and get response back using getjson method?

Tags: javascript, ajax, getjson

I want to post textarea data to a php form and get its response back to another textarea. could you guys tell me how this can be done? I tried following but it doesn't work!

```
$.post(url, dataToBeSent, function(data, textStatus) {

   url="./doit.php";
   var dataToBeSent = $("myform").serialize();

var siteContents2 = data.contents;  
document.myform2.outputtext2.value = siteContents2 ;

}, "json");
```

forms:

```
<form id="myform" name="myform" action="./ok1.php?Id=&title=" method="post">
<td><textarea rows="7" cols="15" name="outputtext" style="width: 99%;"></textarea></td>

</form>

<form id="myform2" name="myform2" action="./ok2.php?Id=&title=" method="post">
<td><textarea rows="7" cols="15" name="outputtext2" style="width: 99%;"></textarea></td>

</form>
```

php get data passed beg getjson:

```
$passed3 = $_post['dataToBeSent'];
echo $passed3;
```

Comment: What errors do you get? It seems that you try to define `url` and `dataToBeSent` within your callback function, which can't work, because they have to be passed to `$.post()` as parameters. Also, refer: [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Comment: Thanks for reply. can you tell me how i can pass them ? i dont get any error . I just dont get any response back!

Comment: can you provide a JSFiddle so we can test around, see what's going wrong?

Comment: Just define you post data and url before calling `$.post()` and then pass these variables.

Comment: @Voles I think it's hard to implement a working fiddle that uses `$.post()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define the URL and data in the callback function. You need to define them before you call `$.post()`. You can try it with the code below, this is the '*shorthand*' version with `$.ajax()`.

#### JS

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: 'POST',
    url: './doit.php',
    data: $("#myform").serialize(),
    success: function(data)
    {
        $('.result').html(data);
        $('textarea[name="outputtext2"]').val(data);
    }
});
```

#### PHP

```
$formData = $_POST;
echo $formData['outputtext'];
```

More information about POST-requests with jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: Have you tested that? To me it looks like you can't pass a configuration object to `$.post()`.

Comment: This looks better now. Still, I don't quite understand the dot at the url's beginning. Is that some special syntax I don't know about?

Comment: Thanks guys. Voles i didn't see you updated the code now it works fine i get response back from php. If i only want to pass some string instead of form data or passing some data variable via post how i should do it ?

Comment: @user1788736 Please do some research about [POST requests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)). POST parameters are basically encoded key value pairs. You can simply build a POST string in javascript, google gives you thousands of examples.